# Powershell- export a multiple line string to different rows in csv

Tags: powershell

I have a 2 string outputs that stored in variables like this. Need each line in string 2 to be stored in different rows of csv.
String 1 $var1 `89631`
String 2 $var2

```
  0236593
None
66398553 
996325
None
369318
66935
```

Tried to convert string 2 in to an array as I need to get them in different rows.

```
$Newvar2= $var2 -replace("`n",",")
$Var2Array=@($Newvar2)
$objresult= New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Id number"=$var1; "Orders"=$var2Array} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But in the csv the string data data is getting stored in a single row, where as I need them in different rows.
Also tried to Add-Content but it also stores the string in one single row.

```
$Var2array=($var2 -split '\r?\n').Trim()
Add-Content -path $filepath -value "'"$var1'",'"$var2array'""
```

Desired output (orders in different rows) csv file-

```
Id number,Orders
89631,0236593
      ,None
      ,66398553 
      ,996325
      ,None
      ,369318
      ,66935
```

Output I am getting (orders in one row) csv file-

```
Id number",Orders
89631,0236593
        None
        66398553 
        996325
        None
        369318
        66935
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of the desired output ? As it is now, the data you show does not contain the `89631` you mention so for me this is unclear

Comment: I have added it. The `89631` is 1st column data and my issue is with second column data comin in a single row

Answer (score 0):

If you want the $var1 to be the same on each row, you could do something like:

```
$var1 = 89631
$var2 = Get-Content "path to orders"

$var2 | Foreach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Id number"=$var1; "Orders"=$_} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Output (CSV File):

```
"Id number","Orders"
"89631","0236593"
"89631","None"
"89631","66398553 "
"89631","996325"
"89631","None"
"89631","369318"
"89631","66935 "
```

Comment: I did not understand this `$var2 = Get-Content "path to orders"`  $var2 has the string data in it, what foes Get-Content do here

Comment: It was just to get the same variable as you (saved the array of data in a txt file). You can just use the $var2 as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it, note the use of [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#split-and-join-operators) to convert the string stored in `$var2` into an array.

```
$var1 = 89631
$var2 = @'
0236593
None
66398553
996325
None
369318
66935
'@

# convert the string into an array
$var2 = $var2 -split '\r?\n'

0..([math]::Max($var1.Count, $var2.Count) - 1) | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Id number' = $var1[$_]
        'Orders'    = $var2[$_]
    }
}
```

The output would become:

```
Id number Orders
--------- ------
    89631 0236593
          None
          66398553
          996325
          None
          369318
          66935
```

You can then pipe the result of the loop to `Export-Csv` to get the desired result.